# Jikoshoukai for Interview. 「My Strength and Weakness are...」

Tags: grammar, translation, english-to-japanese

I'm kinda new here so please kindly tell me if have broke any rule.

I'm currently doing my Jikoshoukai for my upcoming interview and kinda stuck on some part of my translation. Note Im just N5 when it comes to my nihongo level. I want it to be sound more simple and natural but acceptable for an office base job.

Here is what I have so far:

始めまして！
「Full Name」と申します。
「Age」さいです。
「City」に住んでいます。

「Year」年に「University」大学をそつぎょうしました。
せんもんは機械工学科です。

そつぎょうご、「Company」と言う会社でしごとをしはじめました。
しごとは「Job title」です。

This part is where I'm stuck:

> I want to say:
>
> - "My strength are Keen observation and Logical Reasoning".
>       長所は、鋭い観察と論理です。 (ちょうしょは、するどいかんさつとろんりです。)
> - "My weakness is I'm too strict at checking"
>    弱点は、厳しい確認すぎます。(じゃくてんは、きびしいかくにんすぎます。)
> - "My weakness is I don't know when to quit a Project"
>       弱点は、止めるの時プロジェクトを知りません。(じゃくてんは、やめるのときプロジェクとをしりません。)

日本で仕事がしたいます。新しくて凄い技術を習いたいですから。
それと、私のデサインは前より上手になります。

This is all what I got so far. Feel free to correct my Jikoshoukai.

ありがとう。

Comment: I probably wouldn't use '弱点'. You could use something like '短所' but I think '苦手なこと' is more natural. You should probably also state how you're working to improve in these areas. Edit-And '得意なこと' might be better than '長所'.

Comment: Thank you very much! But currently Im not familiar how to use 苦手なこと it in a sentence.

And thank you for your advice, i'd probably add my plan for improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

長所は、鋭い観察力と論理的思考です。

短所は、厳格にチェックしようとして神経質になりすぎることです。

もう一つの短所は、プロジェクトの止め時がわからないことです。

日本で仕事がしたいです。新しくてすばらしい技術を習いたいですから。

それと、私のデサインは以前より上手くなると思います。

Comment: Thank you very much!
But would you mind explaining?
Specially the use of 神経質.

Doumo arigatou.

Comment: 短所は、厳格にチェックしようとしすぎることです。is also fine. But when you refer your character as a demerit, 神経質になりすぎる is a very popular, common and idiomatic expression, I think. It's easy to understand for Japanese people, I think.

Comment: Does it mean I'm worried that Im too strict at checking?
I'll probably use your answer. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: 神経質 itself is a negative word. So some people might think that the without-神経質-version would be better.  I, however, recommended it for you because in your context, you were referring to your demerit, and using 神経質になりすぎる may be regarded as you're an honest person. But it depends on the listener. You may wait for other member's comment or answer.